# SQL Server Not IN

Tags: sql-server

Im having troubles in making a query that do me the following:

I want to search for a specific record, let's say `ordfab` in the database, which has the attribute `mov_type = S` and not `mov_type = E`. For example:

```
id   ordfab   mov_type
1    001      E
2    002      E
3    003      E
4    001      S
5    002      S
```

The query im working with starts with the following:

```
select * from MOV_PROD where ORDFAB in (001, 002, 003) and mov_type = 's';
```

Now i want to make sure the selected rows are only ordfabs that have mov_type 'e' and not both. The result would be 003.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advances,
John

Comment: what type is ordfab, number or string?  If number then the in statement should be `(1,2,3)` if string then it should be `('001', '002', '003')`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an ant-join pattern, using a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and a WHERE clause:

```
select s.* from MOV_PROD s 
  LEFT
  JOIN MOV_PROD e
    ON e.ordfab = s.ordfab
       AND e.move_type = 'E'
 WHERE e.ordfab IS NULL
   AND s.ORDFAB in (001, 002, 003) and s.mov_type = 's'
```

The "outer join" will return all rows from "s", along with matching rows from "e" if any matching rows are found. The WHERE clause filters out all the rows that had a match, so you are left with rows from "s" that didn't have a matching row from "e".

Because the table is referenced more than once, the column references need to be qualified, to avoid an "ambiguous column" error. The only change I made to your original query was to add a table alias and qualify the column references, and relocate the existing predicates after the JOIN.

(It's a bit odd to see leading zeros on the values of ordfab in the IN list...)

This is just one way. There are other ways to get an equivalent result, such as using an IN predicate or an EXISTS predicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT M1.*
FROM mov_prod M1
WHERE M1.mov_type = 'E'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1
               FROM mov_prod M2
               WHERE M2.mov_type = 'S'
               AND M2.ordfab = M1.ordfab);
```

Comment: this one might work thank you :P what about the ORDFAB in (001, 002, 003) part ?

Comment: you can add that in the nested query, I just assumed it was not needed

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to think of this, select all items with type S, join to all items of type E, take the ones where no join exists:

```
select * 
from MOV_PROD withE
left join MOV_PROD withS ON withE.ordfab = withS.ordfab and withS.mov_type = 'S'
where withE.mov_type = 'E'
  and withS.ordfab is null
```

I think this is the clearest way to solve this problem.

---

If you need the other qualifier (or anything else) just add it in:

```
select * 
from MOV_PROD withE
left join MOV_PROD withS ON withE.ordfab = withS.ordfab and withS.mov_type = 'S'
where withE.mov_type = 'E'
  and withS.ordfab is null
  and ORDFAB in (001, 002, 003) -- should be (1,2,3) or ('001', '002', '003')
```